# HTTP::Cookies to Mojo::UserAgent::CookieJar

Tags: perl, cookies, lwp-useragent, mojo-useragent

I have `$cookie_jar` which created using [HTTP::Cookies](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Cookies):

```
$cookie_jar = HTTP::Cookies->new(
  file => "my$path/my_cookies.dat",
  autosave => 1,
);
```

I want to use this `$cookie_jar` using [Mojo::UserAgent](https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojo/Cookie) but didn't find an option, the only option I see is parsing raw string:

```
my $cookies = $cookie->parse($str);
```

Comment: I've uploaded a new version of HTTP::Cookies::Mozilla and it includes a sample program that solves this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've uploaded a new version of [HTTP::Cookies::Mozilla](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Cookies::Mozilla) and it includes a sample program that solves this issue.

---

Load your data using `HTTP::Cookie` then convert it whatever format that you like by calling `scan` with a callback:

```perl
$cookie_jar = HTTP::Cookies->new(
  file => "my$path/my_cookies.dat",
  autosave => 1,
);
$cookie_jar->scan( \&callback )
```

Inside that callback, convert it to the `Mojo::Cookie::Response` object:

```
{
my $jar = Mojo::UserAgent::CookieJar->new

# access the scoped variable after you've run all the callbacks.
sub jar { $jar }

sub callback {
    my( $version, $key, $val, $path, $domain, $port, 
        $path_spec, $secure, $expires, $discard, $hash ) = @_;

    my $cookie = Mojo::Cookie::Response->new;
    ...fill in data...

    $jar->add( $mojo_cookie);
    )
}
```

Alternately, write a subclass of `HTTP::Cookies` that reads your format the `HTTP::Cookies` way but populates a `Mojo::CookieJar` instead. It's not that hard (and I've written several such things, some of which are on CPAN).

<strike>`HTTP::Cookies` also has the `as_string` method which makes a multi-line string with one cookie per string. You can use those lines to feed into `Mojo::Cookie` to re-parse them, but that's not as appealing to me.</strike>

Comment: I thought about the as_string method but it won't work, it creates a string in the same format it exports to, not in the format that would be expected from response data by other cookie jars. scan is probably the best bet.

Answer (score 1):

They are not compatible objects, and nothing other than HTTP::Cookies can read the file it creates. You need to use a [Mojo::UserAgent::CookieJar](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::UserAgent::CookieJar) with Mojo::UserAgent. Note that it will create one by default, accessed via $ua->cookie_jar. It does not have file serialization support, but the [Persistent role](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::UserAgent::CookieJar::Role::Persistent) can add this functionality -- it still will not read the HTTP::Cookies format however.

Comment: I see ,What i am trying to do is to use HTTP::Cookies::Mozilla which is a subclass of HTTP::Cookies to copy all my Firefox cookies to mojo::cookies and use them with Mojo::UserAgent , what is the fast solution to do this ?